# How to get the services from the website

Tags: javascript, c#

If i want to fetch the data from the website (any website), I understood that we need to get the services for that website. Services will get from the API.
So, how to find the services for the website?

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong in the question and help me understanding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not all websites have public services. If they do they will have documentation on its API. That documentation will usually be on the website.

Comment: What type of data you want to fetch? If it's part of the content that you see on your browser then you just need to parse the html you get in response to the request. And if it is not then @Andy is write, not all websites have public services

Comment: @Andy : As you said, not all websites have public services. That means is it possible to fetch the data for the websites which is not having any services?

Comment: If they have no services what data are you talking about?

Comment: I have a data (data like status information in a website page). So once i login to the data, i have to select the dropdowns to filter the data FROM and TO (Where i requrie the data only from those dates). So i will get a requried data.

Comment: @Andy: What i understood is, if we don't have services, there won't be any data? Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If to speak about C# available options, then you can get access to Web services which implemented MEX http. For that cases you can use [Metadataresolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.metadataresolver(v=vs.110).aspx) at C# server side.

Answer (score -1):

Guess you want to crawl websites.Not every website open their apis.

fetch and parse pages may be the only way to crawl datas.

Comment: How to whether that website is having the API open or not.